# Unable to change color of the switch using css

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

My objective is to change the color of the Switch in yellow color (while switching on). I've tried to change the color of the Switch but couldn't do it. Is it possible to change color?

```
 <Switch
                size="small"
                checked={this.state.switchChecked}
                onClick={this.handleSwitchState}
                color="yellow"
              />
```

Can anyone please help me in this query? I want to show yellow color when we Switch it.

Comment: The `color` attribute has to be one of the pre-defined ones for the Switch component, e.g. `primary/secondary/etc.`. If you look at the docs you can see how they implement custom colors, check the source code of the examples: https://material-ui.com/components/switches/#customized-switches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize the color, you will have to use `FormControlLabel` instead of `Switch` and then set the colors you want inside `color`, `"&$checked"` and `"&$checked + $track"`.

```
import React from "react";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { yellow } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

const PurpleSwitch = withStyles({
  switchBase: {
    color: yellow[300],
    "&$checked": {
      color: yellow[500]
    },
    "&$checked + $track": {
      backgroundColor: yellow[500]
    }
  },
  checked: {},
  track: {}
})(Switch);

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    switchChecked: false
  };

  handleSwitchState = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { switchChecked: !prevState.switchChecked };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { switchChecked } = this.state;
    return (
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <PurpleSwitch
            checked={switchChecked}
            onChange={this.handleSwitchState}
            name="switchChecked"
          />
        }
        label="Yellow color"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm getting error in this way - Type '"red" | "yellow"' is not assignable to type '"default" | "primary" | "secondary" | undefined'.

Comment: can you assist me how to write this properties in css file ?